# How to avoid 64K method limit with dexguard integration?

Tags: android, gradle, dexguard

I have used **dexguard** for the next level security of my Android App. I updated to latest version of **dexguard** which is **8.3.03**. In the documentation of **dexguard** they said that, `multiDexEnabled=true` is longer supported. 
Now my application code and user libraries reached the 64K limit and android studion dont let me create relase APK. 
How to let the gradle accept multiple dex files while creating APK ?
Please help,
Thank you
Cheers

Comment: Hi did you find a solution for this ? `-multidex` is not working on latest dexguard version 8.5

Comment: @SharpEdge did either of you find a solution?

Comment: @Hala.M yes Sagar's Answer worked for me `-multidex` at the top of Dexguard file. This should be the very first line.

Answer (score 1):

Dex guard will handle the multidxing part here,

All you have to do is add **-multidex** line in the dexguard-project.txt at the top

and in your gradle file **multiDexEnabled  false**

Answer (score 0):

Dexguard provides its own solution to multiDexing. To enable this you need to add the `-multidex` in your dexguard rules file. It only works from Android 5.0 and up.

Hope this helps